# What does 'parse-time' mean? Does it mean rendering?

Tags: asp.net, parsing

When I was reading Asp.Net Expressions article, I have seen such a sentence:

"Expressions are evaluated at run time when the declarative elements of the page are parsed, and the value represented by the expression is substituted for the expression syntax. (Because expressions are evaluated at **parse time**, you cannot dynamically create expressions in code.)"

Where does the parse-time exist in terms of page life-cyle? Rendering?

Comment: Sounds like "compile time", but for stuff that's parsed and then compiled, like ASP.NET Web Forms .aspx and .ascx items.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the "code front" or the "aspx" page is interpretted each time a request for it is made. At the time of this request the aspx page is consumed or *parsed* by the asp.net dll. This would be the point in time they are referencing in this blurb.